# Pine Editor Nz function gives symbol resolve error

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

hello i have a problem with tradingview and this code , if i am not wrong  , nz should replace NaN  With zero in this case , so i should be able to plot zero in those symbol like DXY EURUSD ZN1!

`//@version=5 indicator("My script") grahamnumber = nz( request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, "GRAHAM_NUMBERS", "FY", currency= currency.USD),0) plot(grahamnumber)`

the result instead it's that  the script can be compiled but it gives you an error on the chart like this :
symbol resolve error:={"currency-id"_"USD". "symbol":"FUND:CBOT_DL;ZN1!;GRAHAM[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution : ignore_invalid_symbol=true basically if it's true the error doesn't appear anymore and the plot shows correctly the value 0 if the symbol has not the graham number instead if it has it shows you the correct value.

```
//@version=5 
indicator("My script")
grahamnumber = nz(request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, "GRAHAM_NUMBERS", "FY",ignore_invalid_symbol=true,  currency= currency.USD),0)
plot(grahamnumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no financial data available for futures, so any attempt to use `request.financial()` on futures symbols will result in a similar error. The error itself indicates that the script requests a symbol that could not be found.

Comment: that was very clear from the beginning  and infact i tried to fix it with nz() function but it did not work it turned out that  you have to add  ignore_invalid_symbol=true to  request.financial() to fix it